# MongoDB: Query Time Series Collection Filtering Based on Sub Collection Matches

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

My time series collection looks like below. I believe the `key` and `value` properties are unnecessary, redundant, and wrong, however I have no control over that. I simply need to be able to search based on timeseries is less-than and/or greater than AND specific `key`/`value` pairs; for example: return all documents between x and y date where `key` `app-name` has `value` `app1` AND `key` `env` has `value` `prod`.

I am trying to build an aggregation pipeline and was hoping there was a Mongo guru out there that could help me out.

```
  { key: 'app-name', value: 'app1' },
  { key: 'app-tier', value: 'web' },
  { key: 'env', value: 'prod' }
```

```
[
  {
    timestamp: ISODate("2022-11-25T21:00:17.000Z"),
    metadata: {
      name: 'VM-Web01',
      source: { id: '500570f3-3562-9b33-aaaa-2975b3e82932', system: 'comp' },
      type: 'vm'
    },
    host: { node: 'cmp-comp1.lab.local' },
    tags: [
      { key: 'app-name', value: 'app1' },
      { key: 'app-tier', value: 'web' },
      { key: 'env', value: 'prod' }
    ],
    _id: ObjectId("12342ce8e43af3c98357d253"),
    power: { state: 'running' }
  }
]
```

Comment: `$and` with each pair represented in `$elemMatch` objects

Comment: @user20042973 thank you! I was hoping for the complete BSON query but I'll take it!

Answer (score 0):

A query that worked is:

```
  "timestamp": {
    $gte: new Date("2022-10-25T21:00:17.000Z"),
    $lt: new Date("2022-12-25T21:00:17.000Z")
  },
  tags: {
    $all: [
      {
        "key": "app-name",
        "value": "app1"
      },
      {
        "key": "env",
        "value": "prod"
      }
    ]
  }
}).toArray();
```